# Why does Gnome System monitor never tell me what process is actually using the CPU?

Tags: 11.10, cpu-load, system-monitor

I have an applet in my Gnome Panel which shows me the current load of my CPU. This is important on my laptop because it's a slightly older machine, and so knowing when I should let it finish one task before starting another stops me from getting frustrated with it.

However, sometimes when the CPU is maxing out at 100%, and stays there for a while, it can be an indication that something has gone wrong and maybe I should kill the process.

However, I've noticed over years of using Ubuntu that the System Monitor never really informs me what's going on.

Take for example, this screenshot (the interface is in Japanese, but that shouldn't change the problem):

[image: CPU Load]

Just above the System Monitor itself is my panel applet, where the box filled with green just to the right of the battery indicator is also indicating 100% CPU usage.

Now look at this image:

[image]

Nothing is using any more than 7% of the CPU.

This seems to be very frequently the case - I dare say almost always - that when the CPU is maxing out, I can never see what is actually using those CPU cycles.

I have tried using HTOP at the command line as well, but the results are the same.

Why does the System Monitor always show me 100% CPU use in general, but never more than a few % when I look at the total of specific processes?

What am I supposed to do when I want to figure out what is using so much CPU time, should I want to to kill runaway processes, or at the very least know what the process is?

Comment: did you activate the view of "all processes" in the menu ?

Comment: @CédricJulien: Wow! No... I hadn't enabled that option... because I never looked for it... because I always assumed that was the *point* of the System Monitor, so I never imagined it was an option I should look for. Huh. Well... let me give that a whirl for a while and see if it helps. If it turns out that's the issue, then you should put it as an answer.

Comment: alternatively you can use the console command top

Comment: @MichaelK: As I mentioned in the question, I tried HTOP, which is the same thing so far as I know, but it also doesn't show me all the processes. However, maybe that's because I'm not selecting all the right options there, either.

Comment: Did activating "all processes" solve this question?

Comment: @coversnail: Yes, it seems to have solved the problem. Someone can get some easy rep by putting that as an answer. ;)

Comment: I have this same problem even with "All Processes" selected. I'm wondering whether a lot of processes with 0.X% CPU usage are being rounded down to 0% in the System Monitor columns, despite adding up to something like 75% overall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by Cedric Julien in the comments,

To view all the processes that are using CPU, when using System Monitor, go to the **View** menu and select **All Processes**

[image]

Comment: I still have the same problem as OP even with "All Processes" selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KSysGuard](https://userbase.kde.org/KSysGuard), which by default shows all processes, looks a bit nicer (e.g. alternate colors for the row of processes), and has more options than System Monitor.

[image: KSysGuard vs. System Monitor]

You don't need KDE to use KSysGuard on Ubuntu. Just run `sudo apt install ksysguard`.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed two phenomena that could account for the discrepancy OP is seeing, and which aren't often mentioned in answers to questions like this. Sadly, they're not that helpful in terms of identifying the actual process.

1. At the command line, you can observe a list of processes with resource usage by using the `top` command. In particular, you should see a line like this:

   ```
   %Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 24.9 id, 74.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
   ```

   Press `1` to show this per-individual-CPU. You should see something like:

   ```
   %Cpu0  :  1.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 98.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
   %Cpu1  :  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 99.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
   %Cpu2  :  0.3 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 99.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
   %Cpu3  :  1.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
   ```

   The above information was taken from a situation when System Monitor showed 0% CPU usage for all processes except itself, but the panel applet showed fluctuating usage between 72% and 78%. Note that while CPU 3 shows 98.3% idle, the other CPUs show high percentage values for `wa`.

   What does `wa` signify? Well, I'm not sure if the rules prevent linking to other Stacks, but there's an excellent question on unix.SE which includes this description:

   `wa: io wait cpu time (or) % CPU time spent in wait (on disk)`

   So the panel applet is showing high CPU usage from processes that are waiting on disk I/O, but the CPU cycles involved in this are not reported by System Monitor itself. I also haven't been able to get this information to show in `htop`.

   BTW, I understand that this waiting-on-I/O state is known as "iowait".

   I'm trying to find out whether other tasks can use the CPU while it's in iowait, instead of leaving it stuck in idleness, but I'm not having much luck finding this information.
2. In MATE's System Monitor, the percentage values in the "CPU Usage" column are all integers. I'm not sure whether the actual values are rounded up, down, or to the nearest integer. But if they're not being rounded up, ten processes with 0.3% usage each could all show as 0%, even though their actual usage would add up to three percent.

Like OP, I have a fairly old machine, so the discrepancy between:

- CPU usage (as reported by the panel applet)
  and
- total usage (as obtained by adding up the percentages in the System Monitor CPU columns)

is very frustrating when the panel reports high usage but I can't find any process that could account for it!